# Why do event triggers created by an AJAX request have to be in the AJAX request itself?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

Why does this work:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/some/url.php",
    data: { s:"stuff" },
    success: function(result)
    {
        // Result being <button id="clickme">Click me!</button>
        $("#container").html(result); 

        // Event trigger *in* AJAX
        $("#clickme").on("click", function()
        {
           alert("Hai"); 
        });
    }
});
```

And this doesn't:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/some/url.php",
    data: { s:"stuff" },
    success: function(result)
    {
        // Result being <button id="clickme">Click me!</button>
        $("#container").html(result); 
    }
});

// Event trigger outside AJAX, for better overview, like event grouping, 
// shorter AJAX functions, etc
$("#clickme").on("click", function()
{
    alert("Hai"); 
});
```

Using jQuery `v1.7.2`

Comment: it should work if you use .live instead of .on

Comment: Are you using the latest jQuery, it should work if you are

Comment: I'd rather not use `.live` as it is deprecated

Comment: is the #clickme item added in the ajax response? If so you won't have access to it until success is called.  Remember that the A in Ajax stands for asychronous...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `on` doesn't use delegation with that signature. That means it directly attaches the event listener to the found elements.

Secondly, your second code is executed before the ajax request is even made, so no elements are found at this point and the code does not attach any event listeners.

If you wanted to use delegation with `on`, the signature goes like:

```
$(document).on( "click", "#clickme", function(){

});
```

Where `document` *should* be closest static parent element - but it works with `document` as well (that's what `.live` does after all)

`document` is reliable because it's always there. But if you have a closer static parent element that can be found at this point in the DOM, you could rather delegate to that.

---

The reason `document`, `"body"` etc are not recommended is because they add a processing overhead for all `type` events on the page.

Consider `$(document).on("mousemove", ".myElement", fn);`

Now, anytime the mouse is moved on the page, unless propagation is stopped by lower level listeners, jQuery has to process through the entire propagation path
every time to see if any element in the propagation path matched the given `.myElement`-selector.

If you instead added `$("#element").on("mousemove", ".myElement", fn);`, this processing would only be done for mousemove events that happen 
in the `"#element"` area on the page.

Comment: I thought .live() would work even on dynamically loaded content, but now it's deprecated, I wander if last implementation of .on() does this by default...

Comment: @Onheiron well, it's deprecated because it's confusing as hell. It doesn't exactly say *delegation to document*. `.on` just makes that fact more explicit.

Comment: Anything on `$("body")` vs `$(document)`?

Comment: @GeenHenk `document` works always, `"body"` works only if the body element exists at that point.

Comment: This works really well, thanks! Now I can split my uber-long AJAX functions into AJAX-parts and event-parts and get a lot more overview.

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
$('body').on("click", "#clickme", function() {
    alert("Hai"); 
});
```

your second snippet doesn't work as you expected because when you attach the handler the element `#clickme` doesn't exist yet

Comment: Please, someone could explain his downvote so I can improve my answer or correct myself for the good of the community? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

`$(document).on("click", "#clickme", function() {
    alert("Hai");
});`

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the 2nd case the element you're trying to set the click-handler on doesn't exist on pageLoad.

If you use .on() like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#clickme", function()
{
    alert("Hi"); 
});
```

it would work , because you'd attaching the event to the body tag, which exists at page load, then  the selection of #clickme  is only resolved when a click event fires.

But better than 'body' (for performance) would be some container further down the DOM that you know will exist on pageload.